# Bitwise 'or' of all the rows of a matrix in one step

Tags: matlab

```
>> a = logical(randi([0 1] , 3,3))

a =

 0     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     0     0
```

Consieder the above example. Is there a way to take a bitwise 'or' of the whole matrix rows in one step? So I get something like:

`ans = 1 1 0` in the end

Comment: Thanks solves my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) function, from the docs:

> In practice, any is a natural extension of the logical OR operator.

In your case it is simply

```
any(a)
```

Like most MATLAB functions, you can choose the dimension for `any` to operate over using the second input so to get it operate over the columns instead of rows

```
any(a,2)
```

If you wand the equivalent for `&&` instead of `||` then use [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html)

> In practice, all is a natural extension of the logical AND operator.

Comment: Thanks for a better solution !

Comment: wouldn't `any(a)` just equal `1` in this case? i think he'd need to do something like `ans(1)=any(a(1,:)); ans(2)=any(a(2,:)); ans(3)=any(a(3,:));` ,and that wouldn't be one step, or am i wrong?

Comment: @Brocodile any(a) takes non zero elements in row dimension by default so any(a,1) is the same

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer